# VSCode is checking my static resource JS files as if they are LWC

Tags: javascript, vs-code

I have some JS files in a static resource. I pulled code from a Production org and converted to DX format for convenience. I am noticing when I open them in VSCode I get errors like **"LWC1007: c:\foo\detailController.js: Unexpected reserved word 'package' (887:44)"**

However this JS file does not contain a Lightning Web Component. It's a static resource we use in Visualforce.

Any ideas what I need to do to stop VSCode from treating it like it's LWC?

Comment: Do you happen to have a file called `.eslintrc.json` in the `staticresource` folder or any of the parent folders? That could be causing this problem.

Comment: Good question... not that I can see. There are two OTHER static resources with `.eslintrc` files but not these ones.